# python, I want to use function in for loop

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

I want to use `sub_code_stop` in for loop (in list)

```
sub_change = [[0, '150', 'aaa'], [0, '151', 'ccc'],
              [0, '152', 'bbb'], [0, '152', 'ddd']]


def sub_code_stop(a):
    for cc in sub_change:
        if a == cc[1]:
            return cc[2]
        else:
            return 0


lis = [['150', '151'], ['152', '153']]
for i in lis:
    print(sub_code_stop(i[0]))
```

Return is

```
aaa
0
```

I want

```
aaa
bbb
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the function to:

```
def sub_code_stop(a):
    for cc in sub_change:
        if a == cc[1]:
            return cc[2]

    return 0
```

Your previous code was comparing with only the first element of `sub_change`.

---

If the second element of each sublist in `sub_change` were unique, you could do:

```
sub_change = [[0, '150', 'aaa'], [0, '151', 'ccc'],
              [0, '152', 'bbb'], [0, '153', 'ddd']]
sub_dict = {b:c for _,b,c in sub_change}
lis = [['150', '151'], ['152', '153']]
for i in lis:
    print(sub_dict.get(i[0],0))
```

Comment: the original form of sub_change is
 sub,150,aaa
 sub,151,bbb
 sub,152,ccc
 sub,153,dddd

--------------------------------------
sub_code_stop.csv form is 

    sub,150,aaa
    sub,151,bbb
    sub,152,ccc
    sub,153,dddd
    .
    .
    .

I want to change row[1] in sub_change to row[2]

and allocate it to 2D dictionary like this (first = {'aaa':{'bbb':[]}, 'ccc':{'ddd':[]}}) but the second sub_code_stop('150') return 0

Answer (score 2):

In your current code if the first element does not match, you leave the function with the `return` in the else part. You'll have to continue looping to test the next elements.

If you find something you return the appropriate value. If you don't find anything then you have to deal with that after the loop is finished.

```
def sub_code_stop(a):
    for cc in sub_change:
        if a == cc[1]:
            return cc[2]
    return 0
```